# First time when a image drop on droppable area it was not dragging. but after resize and rotate it will drag

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

here is the link for jsfiddle ..[link](http://jsfiddle.net/yKNKE/16/) but I can't include some script so didn't rotate..those scripts are...

can anyone give me a solution to drag image first time when it drop.

Comment: I think it could be your test var as it was never defined b4 it will be `NaN + 90` or `undefined` which is not going to give you an integer or number if you prefer

Comment: @Val can you please describe it briefly . actually I'm new to jquery.

Comment: what yu wan to to drag? the droped image?

Comment: yes . I want to drag the dropped image first time. because after resize and rotate it will drag. but in jsfiddle it will not shows.

Comment: pff your code is little messy :D

Comment: @omnosis can you please solve this problem. $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());----This line is responsible for drag. but after adding resize and rotation it will not work.

Comment: trying to find out what is the problem. but your code  is tipical "WTF?" :D

Comment: @omnosis thanks for your time. in jsfiddle it will not work properly because I can't include script files. thanks again in advance, I will wail for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/CUJqw/3/

i edited your code a bit and now works :D not really know what was the original problem. try to use this

Comment: but now it was not rotate and resize. I want Rotate, resize and drag all together.

Comment: yes because in fiddler there is no rotate function... anyway i uptad the code again. http://jsfiddle.net/CUJqw/4/

Comment: @omnosis I tried that code but it was rotate. it was removed on single click. and I need resize feature also.

Comment: i cant understand your ptoblem. your problem is with rotate. but there is NO rotate function in JQuery. you mst use a library bt i dont know wich. please provide some code!

Comment: Sorry, it was not rotate and it move below the div. the rotate library is "jQueryRotate.1.7.js"

Comment: yes because the rotate plugin sucks. this replace the item to a span and a canvas

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yKNKE/16/ It works on my page but not on jsfiddle.because here some jquery ui is not included.

Comment: sorry. i cant help for you. you should provide a demonstration. do you have webserver on your computer?

Comment: yes. here is the link [link](http://ushatech.com/customer/Palletized_Material_Handling_Conveyors/build.php?num1=50&num2=50)

Comment: i give you email. rackajuh@gmail.com you can contact me by this. your ideais funny but the coding is horrible :D hope i can help

Comment: yes. i checked. your code is funny :D but your problem is not only this, little more, so please contact me in private, and i will help you.